# VLC Plugin error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, vlc

I'm trying to add VLC plugin as a COM component to WinForm but i get this error.

[image]

I'm using Windows 7 32 bit. And I have the latest version of VLC 2.0.7.

Tried to register the dll using `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll"`

What should I do to make this error go away?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you register the dll in escalated mode. Right click on command prompt and run as Administrator before registering the dll.